# How to use setPersistence in Firebase Modular SDK V9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i try firebase 9 version persistence for login:

```
setPersistence(auth, firebaseApp.auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then( async() => {
  // login
}).catch((e) => {
  this.error = e.message
})
```

show error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Persistence' of undefined
```

any clue?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to import persistence states this way:

```
import {
  getAuth,
  setPersistence,
  browserLocalPersistence,
  browserSessionPersistence,
  inMemoryPersistence
} from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth()

await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
```

| Namespaced Version V8 | Modular Version V9 |
| --- | --- |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` | `browserLocalPersistence` |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION` | `browserSessionPersistence` |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE` | `inMemoryPersistence` |

Comment: thank's man, I didn't read the documentation well

Comment: What about `indexedDBLocalPersistence`? I checked my app and chrome dev tool application tab shows saved firebase data in `IndexedDB` not in `Local Storage`. So maybe that's the default "local"?

Comment: @CSSer Firebase auth does use IndexedDB as per this [conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/wgSvjniKPQI)

Comment: @Dharmaraj Can you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73241218/unable-to-persist-firebase-auth-in-a-react-web-application