# How to setPersistence Firebase Modular SDK V9 in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I'm using Firebase to authenticate my users in Nuxt and I wanted to ensure that once a user logged into Firebase and was authenticated, that they would still be logged in even if I launched a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the very concrete way to do this in Nuxt:

Wherever you initialize your Firebase code add "browserLocalPersistence, getAuth, setPersistence" to your import from "firebase/auth" like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  browserLocalPersistence,
  getAuth, 
  setPersistence
} from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "Your-ApiKey",
    authDomain: "Your-authDomain",
    projectId: "Your-projectId",
    storageBucket: "Your-storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "Your-messagingSenderId",
    appId: "Your-appId",
    measurementId: "Your-measurementId"
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
```

I found this source, which helped me get the syntax: [Where to place code to set Firebase auth state persistence in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078982/where-to-place-code-to-set-firebase-auth-state-persistence-in-vue-js)

There is a difference in syntax between Firebase v8 and Firebase v9. You can also read this post here on Stack, they show you the syntax difference between Firebase v8 vs v9: [How to use setPersistence in Firebase Modular SDK V9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038593/how-to-use-setpersistence-in-firebase-modular-sdk-v9)